# PHP Open Source Tools for Agile Development

Tags: php, open-source, scrum, agile

Hello Everyone,

There are so many Questions on Stackoverflow about Agile tools, but I haven't seen a tool which can be installed on a PHP Server.

I'm just looking for an ***Open Source Scrum Tool*** or just an ***Open Source Scrum Dashboard*** for my Team, which can be installed on my webspace(**php**).

Thank you for Help!

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't considering a hosted tool like Pivotal Tracker?

Answer (score -1):

I havent used online tools for Scrum or Kanban because I prefere Whiteboards for this. But if you ask google for "OpenSource Scrum Tool" you will finde a long list and if I take a look at this I would recommend [agilo](http://www.agile42.com/de/agilo/) for trac to you so you could combine agile technics with classic project managment duties.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you can store it on your web space, but if you have your own server CollabNet is giving away a free 5 user license of ScrumWorks Pro!.

Answer (score -1):

I've been looking into Scrum/Agile recently too. www.planbox.com is an excellent online Agile project management tool. It isn't installable on your own server as far as I know but its definitely worth a mention here. Contact them and they'll show you around the app in a Webinar